# if __name__ == '__main__' doesn't work with unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

When I run this code:

```
from unittest import *


class TestSomething(TestCase):

    def test_thing(self):
        assert True


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

I get AttributeError:

```
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest
__________________
|Long stack trace|
------------------
  File "C:\Users\Mykola_Zomchak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\unittest\case.py", line 588, in run
    result.startTest(self)
  File "C:\programs\PyCharm\helpers\pycharm\teamcity\unittestpy.py", line 226, in startTest
    test_id = self.get_test_id(test)
  File "C:\programs\PyCharm\helpers\pycharm\teamcity\unittestpy.py", line 40, in get_test_id
    test_id = test.id()
  File "C:\Users\Mykola_Zomchak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\unittest\case.py", line 1383, in id
    return self._testFunc.__name__
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'

Process finished with exit code 1
Empty test suite.
```

I'm using Python 3.7.0b4 (v3.7.0b4:eb96c37699, May  2 2018, 19:02:22) [MSC v.1913 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32.
Can someone please help with that?

Comment: `self._testFunc.__name__` from the error suggests that this has nothing to do with the code you posted. It's a problem with `case.py`.

Comment: Works for me. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You should never do `from some_module import *` unless the module documentation explicitly say it is fine. In this case `from unittest import *` breaks everything.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Goyo , I'm gonna read about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not explain the reasons why but if I update your code like below it works as expected. I just followed the documentation example 1:1 but using your class code.

```
import unittest

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_thing(self):
        assert True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

output:

```
[zaphoxx]> uni.py
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

Comment: works for me as well, thanks, but still interesting why my example doesn't work

Comment: adding a print statement after unittest.main() doesn't print though, any idea why?